# Variable no acumula resultados de multiplicación

Tags: javascript

necesito ayuda con javascript por favor:

La variable que declaré (sum) no me acumula la suma de la multiplicación (dato4* dato3):
esto funciona si le quito la condición  if(indice==indice2) pero me da el resultado errado.

```js
var dato1= parseFloat($("input[name='incidencia[]']").val()/100);
var dato2= parseFloat($("input[name='incidencia2[]']").val()/100);
     
$(document).on('keyup', '.form-control', function(event) {

    $("input[name='nota1[]']").each(function(indice, elemento) {
    
        var dato4= ($(elemento).val()); 
        
        if(dato4==0){
          dato4=1;
        }
        
        var sum=0;
        
        $("input[name='ponderacion[]']").each(function(indice2, elemento2) {
          var dato3=parseFloat($(elemento2).val()/100);

            if(indice==indice2){
              sum += (+dato4*dato3);
              console.log(sum); 
              $('#datos').val(sum);     
            }     
        });

    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Agrega tu HTML por favor para poder reproducir tu ejemplo

Comment: What?, a ver, que alguien me diga si efectivamente se puede guardar un array en html, porque si se puede no se que he estado haciendo con mi carrera en html :/, si no se puede hay varias cosas del código que estarían incorrectas, practicamente todo.

Comment: @Riven, no precisamente arreglos, pero sí puedes tener campos de formulario con el mismo nombre, agregando corchetes, para que puedas identificar cada uno. En Javascript accedes a ellos como una colección de elementos y se manejan igual que arreglos. Finalmente, al procesar el formulario (GET/POST/etc) se envían como arreglo.

Comment: Lo que dice @Triby x2

Answer (score 1):

primero decir que no se si esto te vaya a devolver un arreglo de elemento, ya que nunca he usado algo de esta manera:

```
$("input[name='incidencia[]']")
```

Yo por lo general lo hago de esta manera y por lo tanto siempre me devuelve normalmente un elemento solamente:

```
$("input[name='incidencia']")
```

Pero hagamos de cuenta que enrealidad eso siempre te devuelve un arreglo de elementos en javascript, entonces lo que estas haciendo aquí sería incorrecto:

```
var dato1= parseFloat($("input[name='incidencia[]']").val()/100);
var dato2= parseFloat($("input[name='incidencia2[]']").val()/100);
```

Por dos cosas, la primera es que:

```
$("input[name='incidencia[]']")
$("input[name='incidencia2[]']")
```

Si esos dos ambos te devuelven un arreglo de elementos desde javascript, estas intentando entonces sacarle la propiedad value a un arreglo de inputs y no al elemento en sí, lo cuál por supuesto fallará estrepitosamente, ya que la propiedad value hace parte de `HTMLInputElement` y no de `Array`.

Después de eso lo que intentas es dividir aparentemente ambos valores entre 100, pero recordemos que si estos son arreglos, como Array no tiene una propiedad value, o una de dos:

- Te da un error
- Te arroja undefined

Y pues, si te arroja undefined, el resultado de hacer:

```
$("input[name='incidencia[]']").val()/100
$("input[name='incidencia2[]']").val()/100
```

Sería lo mismo que:

```
undefined / 100
undefined / 100
```

Lo cuál da como resultado algo llamado `NaN`, `NaN` significa `Not A Number` en ingles, y es el resultado de hacer una operación matemática imposible o sin lógica, mas no necesariamente es el resultado de multiplicar un numero por algo que no tiene tipo numero, ya que en javascript esto si funcionaria bien si por ejemplo intentas multiplicar un numero por una cadena de texto, **si la cadena de texto contiene un numero valido**.

Ahora bien, poniendo la operación entera:

```
var dato1= parseFloat($("input[name='incidencia[]']").val()/100);
var dato2= parseFloat($("input[name='incidencia2[]']").val()/100);
```

Esto se traduciria a lo siguiente:

```
var dato1= parseFloat(undefined / 100);
var dato2= parseFloat(undefined / 100);
```

Que a su vez se traduce en lo siguiente:

```
var dato1= parseFloat(NaN);
var dato2= parseFloat(NaN);
```

Usar parseFloat con NaN no te va a arrojar ningún error, simplemente te vuelve arrojar NaN, por lo tanto el contenido que realmente tendría dato1 y dato2 es:

```
NaN
```

Bien, prosigamos, ahora aquí tu asumes que el valor que te devuelve:

```
$("input[name='nota1[]']")
```

Es un array de elementos, y pues yo coincido en lo mismo, lo mas probable es que sea eso, luego iteras dentro de el, hasta aquí todo bien. pero vemos lo siguiente:

```
var dato4= ($(elemento).val());
```

Debes tener cuidado con ese valor, ya que si no es un numero las operaciones pueden devolverte `NaN` al hacerlas.

Luego vemos que iteras sobre:

```
$("input[name='ponderacion[]']")
```

Y dentro de la iteración vemos lo siguiente:

```
var dato3 = parseFloat($(elemento2).val()/100);
```

Esto en sí **no es incorrecto** al hacer esto:

```
$(elemento2).val()/100
```

Ya que ahora si estas usando es el atributo `value` de un solo elemento el cuál si existe.

Pero eso si, deberías verificar que tu campo tenga solo numeros, ya que puedes volver a caer en tener un NaN si tu numero no tiene formato adecuado o no es formalmente un numero.

Entonces esto de aquí, si es correcto asumiendo que tu campo solo contenga numeros y el numero sea valido, pero entonces no necesitarias `parseFloat`, por que siendo `$(elemento2).val()` una cadena de texto numerica y `100` un valor entero, entonces javascript convertirá el resultado a un tipo adecuado, en este caso un numero `flotante` o `entero`, por lo cuál en este caso `parseFloat` es redundante.

```
var dato3=parseFloat($(elemento2).val()/100)
```

Por ultimo tenemos:

```
sum += (+dato4*dato3);
```

No veo nada malo, pero no necesitas poner el igual antes de `+dato4` ya que se asume al igual que las matematicas normales que un numero es positivo si no tiene signo:

```
sum += (dato4*dato3);
```

Con esto entonces lo que deberas hacer es primero comprobar mi teoria, es decir, de inicios, ver que te devuelve `$("input[name='incidencia[]']")` y `$("input[name='incidencia2[]']")` si ambos son arreglos de elementos, entonces ya sabemos por que no funciona.

La forma de solucionarlo es ponero un unico name pero en forma de array, es decir, yo veo que tu tienes algo como esto:

```
$("input[name='incidencia[]']")
$("input[name='incidencia2[]']")
$("input[name='incidencia3[]']")
$("input[name='incidencia4[]']")
```

Lo cuál si enrealidad te devuelve arreglos de elementos entonces no tiene sentido, ya que si lo que dice el usuario `Triby` es cierto, entonces podemos agrupar estos elementos con un una unica clave, es decir el campo `name` en tu caso, por lo tanto, tendrías cuatro elementos html con el mismo `name` así:

```
<input type = "text" name = "incidencia[]">
<input type = "text" name = "incidencia[]">
<input type = "text" name = "incidencia[]">
<input type = "text" name = "incidencia[]">
```

En vez de tener algo así:

```
<input type = "text" name = "incidencia[]">
<input type = "text" name = "incidencia2[]">
<input type = "text" name = "incidencia3[]">
<input type = "text" name = "incidencia4[]">
```

Lo cuál ya no los agrupa, es decir, son independientes unos de los otros.

Y entonces en el inicio, en vez hacer esto:

```
var dato1= parseFloat($("input[name='incidencia[]']").val()/100);
var dato2= parseFloat($("input[name='incidencia2[]']").val()/100);
```

Harías esto:

```
var dato1= parseFloat($("input[name='incidencia[]']")[0].val()/100);
var dato2= parseFloat($("input[name='incidencia[]']")[1].val()/100);
```

Así estarías accediendo entonces a un elemento como tal, y no a una lista de elementos, suponiendo que `$("input[name='incidencia[]']"` lo que haga si es devolverte una lista de elementos.

Comment: Sin el HTML del AP es difícil determinar la causa del error, pero todo parece indicar que se debe a falta de índices al tratar de obtener y establecer valores. Qué mal que no realizaste la prueba para ver lo que devuelve el selector con corchetes después de tan buen y excelente análisis. [Ejemplo de arreglo de campos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529443/jquery-get-input-array-field)

Comment: En efecto, entonces retorna una colección de elementos, la cual puede ser accedida por indices, gracias por poner el ejemplo Triby.